# How to host a flutter website in a desired URL ending with '.com'?

Tags: flutter, web-deployment, flutter-web

I am a beginner with flutter web. I have created a website with flutter. How do I host it in web? Like I need a URL in the form https://abcd.com
I have tried opening the index.html file but it gives a empty page after build.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and totally free solution would be to host it with [firebase](https://firebase.google.com).
After creating a project (like 'myFirstFlutter') they provide you a free subdomain (https://myFirstFlutter.web.app)

Do not forget to build your web app.

```
flutter build web
```

after this you find your web app in your build folder inside your flutter project

Comment: Kudos! Thank you.

Comment: could you mark this answer as the solution, to close this question?

Comment: I am still working on it. I have tried with firebase but I want to host it with some other hosting services like aws or zoho.